# How to move a view on touch move on image

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi i am working on tileview .i want to move marker by on touch .i achieved it by doing this

```
switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                dX = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
                dY = view.getY() - event.getRawY();     

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                view.animate()
                        .x(event.getRawX() + dX)
                        .y(event.getRawY() + dY)
                        .setDuration(0)
                        .start();
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
```

but when i zoom image marker position get changed.

like i point a pin somewhere by drop and drag and when i zoom image pin position get changed 
how to resolve this ?

Comment: like i point a pin somewhere by drop and drag and when i zoom image pin position get changed how to resolve this ? - can you explain it better?

Comment: a object is on tileview  which i have to move
i move it on another position and its working fine with the given code .
but when i zoom the tileview the object position get changed

Comment: Object postion is changed !! is it moving back to the place where it was earlier !! or is its postion is  changed relative the Tile View!

Comment: no when i zoom it change its location but when i zoom out back it moves back again to same location

Comment: Check this function if you have to retain the views postion after animation - setFillAfter(boolean fillAfter) ,Android - Animation